# Count jQuery validation errors on ASP MVC page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

Basically, I have a registaration form view like this, but much more fields:

```
<p class="field-line">
   @Html.LabelFor(d => d.LastName)
   @Html.EditorFor(d => d.LastName)
   @Html.ToolTipMessageFor(d => d.LastName)
   @Html.ToolTipImgFor(d=>d.LastName)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.LastName)
</p>
<p class="field-line">
   @Html.LabelFor(d => d.FirstName)
   @Html.EditorFor(d => d.FirstName)
   @Html.ToolTipMessageFor(d => d.FirstName)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.FirstName)
</p>
<p class="field-line">
   @Html.LabelFor(d => d.BirthDate)
   @Html.EditorFor(d => d.BirthDate)
   @Html.ToolTipMessageFor(d => d.BirthDate)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.BirthDate)
</p>
```

and i need to detect every validation error event to detect hard places for improving tooltip text and images.

So i need in every event send about it, even if it would be fixed after validation message.

**Thanks for any help.**

Comment: are you using the unobtrusive validation?

Comment: yes, `jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do that using the `showErrors` methods.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
  showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
    $("#summary").html("Your form contains "
      + this.numberOfInvalids()
      + " errors, see details below.");
    this.defaultShowErrors();
  }
});
```

`errorMap` contains the Key/value pairs, where the key refers to the name of an input field, values the message to be displayed for that input

`errorList` has the message and the element.

**Note :** if you have multiple forms in the page this `show Errors` will be called for all the forms.

Comment: try placing this in the layout page.